# Adding list/string ord() values in Python

Tags: python

Basically, I want to add two lists together, the lists are made up of letters, strings.
I want to add the lists together, but it is not as simple as you may think.
I want to add the VALUE of each letter in one list, to the VALUE of each letter in another list, by the value I mean if I were to do:

```
ord('a') + ord('b')
```

**Not** :

```
'a' + 'b'
```

I will copy-paste my code below for everyone to see, and the output my code shows when I execute it.

```
import itertools
from itertools import cycle
uinput= input("Enter a keyword: ")
word = cycle(uinput)
uinput2= input("Enter a message to encrypt: ")
message = (uinput2)
rkey =(''.join([next(word) for c in message]))
rkeylist = list(rkey)
mlist= list(message)
print(rkeylist)
print(mlist)

encoded1 = [rkeylist[i]+mlist[i] for i in range(len(rkeylist))]
print(encoded1)
```

**Output:**

```
Enter a keyword: keyword
Enter a message to encrypt: Hello, Hello!
['k', 'e', 'y', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'd', 'k', 'e', 'y', 'w', 'o', 'r']
['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ',', ' ', 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '!']
['kH', 'ee', 'yl', 'wl', 'oo', 'r,', 'd ', 'kH', 'ee', 'yl', 'wl', 'oo', 'r!']
>>>
```

As you can see, the lists have been added together, but not the values, just the letters, so it is as if I am doing:

```
'a' + 'b'
```

rather than the code I want it to be:

```
ord('a') + ord('b')
```

Comment: If you want to add the `ord`s, why do you *explicitly add the strings*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are either looking for:

```
>>> uinput=['k', 'e', 'y', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'd', 'k', 'e', 'y', 'w', 'o', 'r']
>>> uinput2=['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ',', ' ', 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '!']
>>> [ord(i)+ord(j) for i,j in zip(uinput,uinput2)]
[179, 202, 229, 227, 222, 158, 132, 179, 202, 229, 227, 222, 147]
```

or:

```
>>> [chr((ord(i)+ord(j))%26+97) for i,j in zip(uinput,uinput2)]
['x', 'u', 'v', 't', 'o', 'c', 'c', 'x', 'u', 'v', 't', 'o', 'r']
```

or:

```
>>> "".join([chr((ord(i)+ord(j))%26+97) for i,j in zip(uinput,uinput2)])
'xuvtoccxuvtor'
```

Note that `%26+97` maps results to valid alphabetic characters.

Comment: +1! just Update uinput2 to what he mentioned in the post, otherwise it would be confusing